# Eclipse Oxygen & org.eclipse.jface giving NullPointerException dialog

Tags: c++, eclipse, git, nullpointerexception, jface

I've researched this one to death online and here.  I've tried cleaning projects and **eclipse -clean** and some other stuff, but so far, no joy.  I can't tie it to any event, either; it just seemed to start happening out of the blue.  This has been a stable use of Eclipse Oxygen for some time.  If I switch to Mars.1 or Neon, I get the same result, making me think that it is a workspace problem, but I don't know the 'guts' of Eclipse that well to go in and start mucking around.  Honestly this looks like a corrupt jar or something to me.

When I expand one of my C++ projects in Project Explorer, all hell breaks loose in the Error Log.  Everything seems to work, if you don't mind the incessant "Problem Occurred" dialog box notifying you of java.lang.NullPointerException.  The only visible thing I can see wrong is that my C++ files no longer have an icon next to them.  Right-clicking on some elements in the **Git Repositories** tab causes the problem as well.

I've not installed anything new.  No plug-ins, editors, etc.  I will continue to beat on this brat, but in the meantime, here is a sample error log entry:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20160915-0230
java.version=1.8.0_101
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US

org.eclipse.jface
Error
Fri Oct 28 10:46:41 CDT 2016
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.misc.ProgramImageDescriptor.hashCode(ProgramImageDescriptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaElementImageDescriptor.hashCode(JavaElementImageDescriptor.java:207)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ImageDescriptorRegistry.get(ImageDescriptorRegistry.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaElementImageProvider.getImageLabel(JavaElementImageProvider.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaElementImageProvider.getImageLabel(JavaElementImageProvider.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaUILabelProvider.getImage(JavaUILabelProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerLabelProvider.getImage(PackageExplorerLabelProvider.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorLabelProvider.getImage(JavaNavigatorLabelProvider.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.findImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getColumnImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider$StyledLabelProviderAdapter.getImage(NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.doUpdateItem(CommonViewer.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.ResourceToItemsMapper.updateItem(ResourceToItemsMapper.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.ResourceToItemsMapper.objectChanged(ResourceToItemsMapper.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(CommonViewer.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer$1.labelProviderChanged(ContentViewer.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.BaseLabelProvider$1.run(BaseLabelProvider.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.BaseLabelProvider.fireLabelProviderChanged(BaseLabelProvider.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.lambda$0(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager$1.run(DecoratorManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager.fireListener(DecoratorManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$3.runInUIThread(DecorationScheduler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4203)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3819)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse bug [502514](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502514).

If I read the bug correctly the editor registry is getting corrupted by a problem in the market place code. Going through the file associations in the preferences may fix it (more details in the bug report).

The bug is marked as fixed in Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2). The fix might be in the recently released Eclipse Oxygen Milestone 3 (4.7M3)

Comment: I visited your link and went in and visited Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations and added vim for .cpp files and made it the default.  I essentially followed "Comment 12" direction but for .cpp files.  You know, I kept getting Marketplace dialogs for C++ related editors and stuff and I tried several times to get them, but always had some problem with one or two of the links not working, so I quit that idea for the moment.  It was probably this that messed things up.  Anyway, good suggestion, and thanks a bunch!